# Routing Problem between Apache2 and Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, routes, apache2

i have an application and it runs on my vps. My Installation is:

Tomcat 6.0 Ubuntu 10 Apache 2.2.14 Spring 3.0.5 JSF 2.0

Although i configure /etc/apache2/http.conf, the requests does not pass from Apache2 to Tomcat so when my domain is clicked, it returns only xhtml content with jsf tags, not pure html.

What do you think about this problem?

My http.conf is :

```
#mysite.com 
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite.com
  ServerAlias mysite.com www.mysite.com 
  ServerAdmin e-feedback@mysite.com 
  DocumentRoot /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/MySiteProject/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  servername mysite.com
  proxypass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/MySiteProject/ 
  proxypassreverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/MySiteProject/
</VirtualHost>
```

Regards, Javi

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first VirtualHost section. It will result in apache serving up the tomcat pages directly.

Also

- check you have mod_proxy installed
- you have the tomcat connector configured correctly